# terminal: how do i pipe the results of grep to open a file

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash

I'd like to `grep` and `open` a file in just one terminal command.

Suppose I'm in this directory:

```
$ ls
1.txt   2.txt   3.txt   4.txt   5.txt
```

and I want to open `3.txt`

I thought I could do `ls | grep 3 | open`

but it looks like `open` doesn't accept piped input. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try `open $(ls | grep 3)`. Depending on your specific needs, you can also skip the `grep` part and use `open $(ls *3*)` (or even `open *3*`) directly.

Comment: What is the difference between `open $(ls *3*)` and just `open *3*`?

Comment: None in this case, good point :-). I assume that the OP had more complex patterns in mind.

Comment: Pro Tip: Always add a `--` before the glob * when doing `ls`, `rm`, `open` and so on. And never create files named "-rf"...

Comment: Parsing `ls` to produce file name arguments is a bad idea. You can get undesirable results if the directory contains file names with spaces that match the pattern/glob.

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
find . -name "*3*" -exec open {} \;
```

Will run open on any file with 3 in it's name from the current directory down.  The spaces and backslash matter in this case.